# Python returns "invalid character in identifier" when input a fraction

Tags: python

Is there a way (some library) that can correctly identify  ½ -0.2 as valid input? It appears that the ½,¼,¾ characters are not recognized by Python.

I searched the net extensively but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: `"½"` is "recognized" by python, but as a string, not a number. You can't use math operations on arguments of mixed strings and numbers, you need to convert to a number first just like you do with `"1" + 2`.

Comment: I'm aware that it's a string. It's coming from an external source and I'm trying to read it in a Python program and use it for calculations

Comment: Like this? `print(eval(input()))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) module from the standard library:

```
import unicodedata
print(unicodedata.numeric('¼'))
```

Output:

```
0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Those characters are unicode symbols, python does not support casting those symbols to float or int by default.

To workaround this you can map the float representation of those characters using a dict

```
divisor_map = {½: 0.5, ¼: 0.25...}
```

You can then check if the input is in the map, and substitute it accordingly